# IIRF Redirection

Tags: url-rewriting, iirf

I'm just trying to figure out what the following block of code is doing with a URL so I can locate the file that its dealing with.  Can anyone help me out?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL}             !/*.deploy?(.*)                                       [I]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL}             !/*.manifest?(.*)                                       [I]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL}             !/Webresource.axd?(.*)                                       [I]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL}             !/Trace.axd(.*)                                              [I]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                    /Default.aspx?404;http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1                    [U,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first 6 line are **conditions** which have to be met in order for the last line containing the rewrite **rule** to be executed.

This means: If the URL does match the first 4 conditions (meaning: *not* match the first 4 regular expressions after the `!`), is *not* a directory *nor* a file, then append the URL to `default.aspx?404;http://` and return that page instead.

The file your dealing with is `Default.aspx`.